# If statement returns wrong result

Tags: c, algorithm

```c
void test(char *buffer, int size)
{
    int length = strlen(buffer);
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == '"')
        {
            int _size = i + size;
            if (_size > length)
                continue;

            if (buffer[i + size] == '"')
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I read the file.

```c
FILE *file = NULL;
size_t filesize = 0;
uint8_t *filebuffer = 0;
            
file = fopen("tokens.txt", "r");
if (file)
{
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
                filesize = ftell(file);
                fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

                filebuffer = calloc(filesize + 1, 1);
                if (filebuffer)
                {
                    fread(filebuffer, 1, filesize, file);

                    for (size_t i = 0; i < filesize; i++)
                    {
                        if (filebuffer[i] == 0)
                            filebuffer[i] = '.';
                    }

                    char array[filesize];
                    strncpy(array, filebuffer, filesize);
                    array[filesize] = '\0';
                    test(array, 59);
                }
            }
```

"array" is char array[filesize];, "filesize" is ftell(file); (the file is valid and not NULL) the content of the file is `asd"12345678912345678912345678912345678911111231231231231231232"asdasdasdasdasdasdss`

[image]

for some weird reason it reaches to the "continue;" when the statement is not true...

Edit: I tried printing the values in the block of the if statement and for some reason I receive ->
Size: 122
Length: 84

Someone have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Start debugging log ` _size , length` directly before the cintinue (after adding the {}-block)

Comment: looks like you edited your code and not rebuild it or saved it...

Comment: The loop condition `i <= length` will include the string null-terminator.

Comment: Most important details are missing: What type is `array`? What is content of `array`? How do you allocate and initialize memory for `array`? What is the meaning of `size`?

Comment: @MrSmith42 `Size: 122 Length: 84` this is weird why is that?

Comment: And please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: @Gerhardh I read some file's content and store it in `char array[filesize];` while filesize is `ftell(file);` (size_t)

Comment: You might be running into Undefined Behaviour. Does `buffer` contain a NUL-terminated string?

Comment: How do you open the file (binary or text mode)? How do you read? Please follow Some programmer dude's request to provide a MCVE

Comment: Re edit: The contents of the file are irrelevant. The size and contents `buffer` and the value of `size` are.

Comment: I've edited the question I hope it is more "readable"...

Comment: Your code is a real mess. Starting with the fact that you try to read starting at the end of the file...

Comment: @ikegami I know ... i'm still learning ... (started 3 days ago)

Comment: Remember that array indexes are zero-based. For an array of `filesize` elements, the valid indexes are `0` to `filesize - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```c
array[filesize] = '\0'; // access outside of array boundaries
```